# Arrange books on a shelf- combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I wonder if I'm correct at this question:

> You have $20$ different books and $3$ of them are books about tennis. In how many ways can you put $12$ books on a shelf if order matters and the $3$ tennis books must be on the shelf?

My attempt was: $3! \cdot P(17,9) \cdot C(12,3)$. There are $3!$ ways to arrange the tennis books, $P(17,9)$ ways to arrange the other books and out of $12$ positions three is supposed to be for tennis. Am I correct?

Comment: If you distinguish between the tennis books, then you are almost right. But I don´t think that this was the intention of the exercise. The right expression is $C(3,3)\times C(17,9)$

Comment: Ok. But then you have to distinguish between the non-tennis books as well.

Comment: Your calculation is correct. So is **Aqua**’s approach below.

Comment: @callculus: Her calculation does distinguish the non-tennis books: she has $P(17,9)$, not $C(17,9)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, I´ve overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

Just 9 book form 17, that you can do on $${17\choose 9}$$ ways and then arrange all 12 book on a shelf that is $12!$ ways. Multiply both and you are done.

Comment: Is that the same as my answer? When I calculate it I get the same number

Comment: @ErikaAlfsson: Yes, it is.